# Lightning messes with a tags in VF pages by prepending /one/one.app#alohaRedirect/ and changing default behavior

Tags: lightning, javascript

Our Appexchange app (Apsona for Salesforce) runs in a VF page, and among other things, creates DOM dynamically, including a tags along the lines of `<a href="/RecordID" target="windowname">icon</a>`  where RecordId is the record ID of an object, as a convenience for the user to click and open the record in a new window. When run under Lightning underneath the main SF menu bar, we notice (via DOM inspector) that after the DOM is created, the href changes to `/one/one.app#alohaRedirect/RecordID`. So it looks like SF is messing with the DOM and the JS behavior in VF pages, even in a separate iframe. But worse yet, it no longer respects the "target" attribute: when the user clicks the icon, it opens the new record in the new window as well as in the current window, thus destroying any context the user has within our app. Why is this? It causes a lot of confusion for our users.

We have also noticed that if our VF page is opened in its own window, without being iframed under the main SF menu bar, this doesn't happen. That's not a workaround we can suggest to users. Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance.